# Django - HTMX: Render forms errors on modal and keep user on same page?

Tags: django, htmx

may you help me to understand how to use HTMX to render Form's Error messages when form is invalid?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Docs says to use an attribute like :

`hx-post="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"` but since I'm already using `method=post` should I still use it or delete it?I'd like users to stay on current page, however, right now when form is invalid users are redirected here: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

**I didn't find a javascript function that opens the modal, so I think it is openened by some javascript implemented by bootstrap itself.**

this is my form:

```
<form class="row my-4 align-items-center" method="post"
                                      action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ login_form.as_p }}
                                    {% if login_form.errors %}
                                        <ul>
                                            {% for field_errors in login_form.errors.values %}
                                                {% for error in field_errors %}
                                                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
                                </form>
```

views:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        print("### Request is post")

        if login_form.is_valid():
            print("### Request is VALID")
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            print("User name", username, "type: ", type(username))
            print("Pass", password, "type: ", type(password))
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                return redirect("/")
        else:
            print(login_form.errors.as_data())
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'errors': login_form.errors})
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm(request)
        context = {
            "login_form": login_form,
        }
        return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'login_form': login_form, 'errors': login_form.errors})
```

my URLs:

```
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views from .views import register_view, email_user_needs_to_verify_email, verify_email, login_view, logout_view, password_reset_request

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
... other URL patterns ...
path('email_verification_required/', email_user_needs_to_verify_email, name='email_user_needs_to_verify_email'), path('register/', register_view, name='register'), path('verify-email/<str:uidb64>/<str:token>/', verify_email, name='verify_email'), path('login/', login_view, name='login'), path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'), path("password_reset", password_reset_request, name="password_reset"), path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='account/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'), path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="account/password_reset_confirm.html"), name='password_reset_confirm'), path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='account/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'), ]
```

**Login Modal opens when users click the sing in button on navbar: ***

````
{% else %}
                                    
  <li class="user"><a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal" href="#">Hello, sign in<i class="fa fa-user ps-2 text-primary"></i></a></li>
  <li class=""><a data-bs-toggle="" data-bs-target=""
              href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Regístrate<i
                                            class="fa fa-user ps-2 text-primary"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
    ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p3Hz.png
````

Answer (score 1):

First: Let me welcome you to the beautiful side of life that is Django and HTMX. You might struggle a little bit at the start to grasp all the concepts but it will be worth it.

As to your question: I think you are missing a lot of the basics of HTMX and how to use it. I would advise you to start with the examples on the HTMX page.

The example that comes closest to what you want to do is the one [about form validation](https://htmx.org/examples/inline-validation/). All the examples on the HTMX site are worth looking into as they teach you the basic concepts.

After that, it will be clear to you what you have to add to your form from above so that it is HTMX enabled.

The next thing you might want to take a look is the [`django-htmx`](https://pypi.org/project/django-htmx/) package. It will allow you to do things like `request.htmx` to check if the request came from HTMX. (Allow me to plug one [blog article that I wrote](https://dev.to/kummerer94/django-and-htmx-i5c) about some advanced Django + HTMX patterns that also include how to make it work with Jinja.)

Finally, as to your problem I would suggest the following plan:

- You need to enable your form so that it will use HTMX. For that, you have to add the `hx-post` attribute.
- You will need to define the `hx-target` attribute on your form-tag, i.e. the element that you want to swap. Why? Because usually, what you do is the following: you validate the inputs of the user in the backend and if you find that there is an error with the inputs, you render the form including the error messages. Then, you send back only the HTML of the form including the errors and replace the old form with that.
- If there are no errors, you want to login the user and forward him to "/". That can be achieved with [HTMX response headers](https://htmx.org/reference/#response_headers). By sending back the `HX-Redirect` header with the value `/`, the user will be redirected to `/`.

That should be all! I am sure that is enough information so that you can achieve what you try to do. Good luck and let me know how it goes!